# Parsing a CSV file with HTML tags into a Rails database?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to import into a Rails database. I've written a rake task to do the parsing for me.

```
task :csv2, [:file] => :environment do |t, args|
  CSV.foreach(args[:file]) do |row|
    issue = {
      "element1" => row[0],
      "element2" => row[3]
    }

  Issue.create(issue)
end
```

It works great, except for one problem. Sometimes, fields in the CSV have html tags and special characters (e.g. < p> and &QUOT ;). When I dump each column into the database, Rails just reads everything in as straight text. How do I get Rails to understand the HTML and adjust accordingly?

Or, if this is a better option, I'll dump the HTML into the database, and just use the View to understand the HTML?

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, SQLite3 3.6.20.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no understanding of HTML in rails! it's just plain characters.

if you want to display stuff in your view, that has been in your database, you need to sanitize it in rails 3 to prevent crosssidescripting.

in order to do this use the `raw` command or make your strings `html_safe`.

Comment: Raw worked perfectly, exactly what I needed. Thanks! Out of curiosity though, Rails didn't understand .html_safe. Any idea why?

Comment: sure it does: ```"some string".html_safe```

Comment: Okay, I was doing `arrayElem.attribute.html_safe`. It was trying to do `html_safe` on an attribute, not a string. So `(arrayElem.attribute).html_safe` works just fine. Any reason to use `raw` over `html_safe` or vice versa?

Comment: depends on the use-case. ```raw``` is just a wrapper that does a ```to_s``` on the object that you pass.

Comment: So if I want the lightest weight option, raw is the way to go?